# the number of execution time of 2 code will differ?

Tags: c++, code-analysis, execution-time

I wonder how many times the 2 piece of code will be executed. Both of them are n times or one of them is n+1 ?

```
int sum=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
sum = sum + i;
```

AND

```
int sum=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
sum = sum + i;
```

Is there anyone to help me ?

**EDIT**
Sınce I got so many , bad comment. I decided to give my real intent to ask this.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
sum = sum + f1(i, n);}

int f1(int x, int n) { 
int sum = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
sum = sum + i; 
return (x + sum); }
```

The exact complexity of this code snippet is O(n*(n+1)) and I want to learn why there is(n+1) instead of o(n*n)

Comment: You didn't even test it?

Comment: Ask yourself what the answer is if n is 1. Btw, you should indent whatever the `for` loop controls (i.e., `sum = …`).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I tested it and according to me, they'll execute same time.However the exact complexity for edited version of this question is O(n*(n+1)) and I wonder where the 1 is comes.

Comment: @MitchWheat then, what is that =

Comment: I think it's O(n*n). By the way, there is no difference between O(n*(n+1)) and O(n*n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which one you use, the program output will be identical;  `i++` and `++i` are not the termination conditions in the `for` loop but are statements evaluated at the end of each iteration.

Note however that `++i` will never be slower than `i++`; as conceptually an object copy has to be taken for the latter. A good compiler will optimise out the copy though.

And a point of style: please indent the line `sum = sum + i;`; it's hard to read otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code complexity of the code is O(n^2). It doesn't matter about looping for n+1 in complexity. O(n+1) = O(n-1) = O(n) so all are same and the complexity can be said to be n^2.